# Django static text model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-middleware, django-flatpages

So basically I have surveys application and there's main user dashboard. There he can see his surveys, new surveys, etc and there's also some static about text.

What I want to do is make that text not static - let administrator edit it. What are my options here. I thought about using flatpages app but that would mean that I would have to write my custom middleware to pass context to flatpages which is overload and writing my custom app only for two static texts seems like too much work.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why would using flatpages mean you'd have to write middleware?

Comment: @Joost to pass extra context to template that I need

Comment: @Bonifacio2 are there any options besides using flatpages and writing custom models for these static texts.

Comment: @Marijus right, that makes more sense. Interested!